# Best structure for my nativescript app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, arrays, nativescript

I want to script an app with nativescript, but I don't know what the best structure would be. I have given data, for example:

```
var items = [
    [["high", "low"], ["wide", "narrow"], ["fat", "thin"]],
    [["black", "white"], ["...", "..."], ["", "..."]],
    [["high", "low"], ["...", "..."], ["...", "..."]],
];
```

On the starting screen should appear the first layer. Got them sepperated in three chategories. So i want to display for example Level 1, 2 and 3.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDZAa.png)

If you click on any of the buttons, you should get to another screen, where all the elements are listed. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C5sQ.png)
There should be a title and an input field. If you enter the second value into the input field, you got it right and an event listener fires.

If you get something right the data should be stored in some way. For example complete all in Level 1 to get to Level 2.

I looked at the getting started tutorial of docs.nativescript.org and its a good description. Its almost what i want, but I'd like to store the information like writen above. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to store the information would be to store it in an object, and within the `items` object you can have arrays for each level.

```
var items = {
    Level1: [["high", "low"], ["wide","narrow"], ["fat","thin"]],
    Level2: [["black", "white"], ["...","..."], ["...","..."]],
    Level3: [["high", "low"], ["...","..."], ["...","..."]]
}
```